Does Akeneo REST API make possible to sort products query results?
Does Akeneo provide custom sorting parameters to the REST API requests? For example, to sort a list of products by name, price, etc.
I searched through the documentation but didn't find any suggestions. I tried some intuitive query parameters, like sort, order, sort_by, order_by, but none of them seem to work

No, the API does not allow you to sort the results
